# Remove Parentheses From NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am having trouble removing parentheses from my `NSMutableArray`. I am filling it with objects retrieved from Parse **PFQuery**. This all works but I am trying to bring objects from this array into a label which is inside a `UITableViewCell`. In my label it is showing:
(
Name
)
Name is the only thing I want it to show but I cannot remove these brackets. This is what I am currently trying:

```
NSMutableArray *flattenArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(NSString *str in [nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
    {
        [flattenArray addObject:str];
    }
    NSString *string = [flattenArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

And then setting my label's text to the string I created at the bottom. I am filling the array with:

```
nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    PFQuery *findData = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Employee_%@", [[PFUser currentUser] username]]];
    [findData setLimit:1000];
    [findData findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                PFObject *name = object[@"clientName"];
                NSMutableArray *arrayPost = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:name, nil];
                [nameArray addObject:arrayPost];
            }
            [table reloadData];
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unable To Load" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why create a single-element array to hold the name at all?  Simple put the name directly into `nameArray`:

```
   PFObject *name = object[@"clientName"];
   [nameArray addObject:name];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. I will approve your answer as soon as it lets me, says I have to wait 10 minutes